Drag and drop PDF from the New Outlook to winform
Drag and drop PDF from the New Outlook to winform doesn't work. It worked fine if I switch to Classic Outlook.
Tested with .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET 8
Classic Outlook works fine with FileGroupDescriptor format.
The New Outlook doesn't work with FileGroupDescriptor and the available formats when running e.Data.GetFormats() are:

DragContext
DragImageBits
chromium/x-renderer-taint
FileDrop
FileNameW
FileName
Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format

I have tried FileDrop, FileNameW and Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format but none of these works.
Error when using FileDrop with the New Outlook:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80040064
  Message=Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject.GetData(FORMATETC& format, STGMEDIUM& medium)
   at System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataInner(FORMATETC& formatetc, STGMEDIUM& medium) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 694
   at System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataFromOleHGLOBAL(String format, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 441
   at System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetDataFromBoundOleDataObject(String format, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 511
   at System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert, DVASPECT aspect, Int32 index) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 265
   at System.Windows.DataObject.OleConverter.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 164
   at System.Windows.DataObject.GetData(String format, Boolean autoConvert) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 1217
   at System.Windows.DataObject.GetData(String format) in System.Windows\DataObject.cs:line 1231
   at PdfSalesOrders.MainWindow.cmdDBreweries_Drop(Object sender, DragEventArgs e) in C:\repos\pdf-sales-orders-test\PdfSalesOrders\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 1139

//This is my winform code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InspectMemoryStream(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16];  // Read more bytes for better inspection
            memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Convert bytes to a hex string for easy inspection
            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
            MessageBox.Show("Hex: " + hex);

            // Reset stream position after reading
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
        }

        private void ProcessMemoryStreamData(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // Buffer to read chunks of the stream
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                // Convert the buffer to a string to search for the beginning of actual content
                string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Look for the %PDF signature or any other meaningful data
                int index = content.IndexOf("%PDF");
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    // Found the start of the PDF, adjust the memory stream position
                    memoryStream.Position = memoryStream.Position - bytesRead + index;

                    // Now, save the MemoryStream from this position onwards
                    SaveMemoryStreamToFile(memoryStream, "output.pdf");
                    return;
                }

                // If no meaningful content found, continue to the next chunk
            }

            // If no content was found, indicate that the file could not be processed
            MessageBox.Show("No recognizable content found in the stream.");
        }

        private string DetermineFileExtension(MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            // Example approach: Check the first few bytes of the stream to determine the file type
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);

            // Reset position after reading
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            // Look for %PDF in the first 256 bytes
            string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            if (content.Contains("%PDF"))
                return ".pdf";
            
            // PDF files start with "%PDF"
            if (buffer[0] == 0x25 && buffer[1] == 0x50 && buffer[2] == 0x44 && buffer[3] == 0x46)
                return ".pdf";

            // XLSX files typically start with "PK" (indicating a ZIP file format)
            if (buffer[0] == 0x50 && buffer[1] == 0x4B)
                return ".xlsx";

            // Additional checks for other formats can be added here

            return string.Empty;
        }

        private void SaveMemoryStreamToFile(MemoryStream memoryStream, string fileName)
        {
            memoryStream.Position = 0;  // Ensure the stream is at the beginning
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
            MessageBox.Show($"File saved as {fileName}");
        }


        private void button1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] fileNames = null;

            try
            {
                //if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileNameW"))
                //{
                //    string fileName = (string)e.Data.GetData("FileNameW");
                //    MessageBox.Show("Dropped file: " + fileName);
                //    // Process the file using the file path
                //}
                //else 
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format"))
                {
                    using (var customDataStream = e.Data.GetData("Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format") as MemoryStream)
                    {
                        if (customDataStream != null)
                        {
                            // Now customDataStream contains the MemoryStream data
                            ProcessMemoryStreamData(customDataStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
                {
                    fileNames = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                    // handle each file passed as needed
                    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
                    {
                        // do what you are going to do with each filename
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor"))
                {
                    //
                    // the first step here is to get the filename
                    // of the attachment and
                    // build a full-path name so we can store it
                    // in the temporary folder
                    //

                    // set up to obtain the FileGroupDescriptor
                    // and extract the file name
                    Stream theStream = (Stream)e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor");
                    byte[] fileGroupDescriptor = new byte[512];
                    theStream.Read(fileGroupDescriptor, 0, 512);
                    // used to build the filename from the FileGroupDescriptor block
                    StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder("");
                    // this trick gets the filename of the passed attached file
                    for (int i = 76; fileGroupDescriptor[i] != 0; i++)
                    { fileName.Append(Convert.ToChar(fileGroupDescriptor[i])); }
                    theStream.Close();
                    string path = Path.GetTempPath();
                    // put the zip file into the temp directory
                    string theFile = path + fileName.ToString();
                    // create the full-path name

                    //
                    // Second step:  we have the file name.
                    // Now we need to get the actual raw
                    // data for the attached file and copy it to disk so we work on it.
                    //

                    // get the actual raw file into memory
                    MemoryStream ms = (MemoryStream)e.Data.GetData(
                        "FileContents", true);
                    // allocate enough bytes to hold the raw data
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
                    // set starting position at first byte and read in the raw data
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    ms.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                    // create a file and save the raw zip file to it
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(theFile, FileMode.Create);
                    fs.Write(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileBytes.Length);

                    fs.Close();  // close the file

                    FileInfo tempFile = new FileInfo(theFile);

                    // always good to make sure we actually created the file
                    if (tempFile.Exists == true)
                    {
                        // for now, just delete what we created
                        tempFile.Delete();
                    }
                    else
                    { Trace.WriteLine("File was not created!"); }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Error in DragDrop function: " + ex.Message);

                // don't use MessageBox here - Outlook or Explorer is waiting !
            }

        }

        private void button1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Data.GetFormats();

            // for this program, we allow a file to be dropped from Explorer
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            { e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; }
            //    or this tells us if it is an Outlook attachment drop
            else if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileGroupDescriptor") || (e.Data.GetDataPresent("Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format")))
            { e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; }
            //    or none of the above
            else
            { e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None; }
        }
    }
}


Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332/treeview-drag-drop-help-invalid-formatetc-structure-exception?

Thanks Diego. I did but it didn't make any different with the e.Handled set to true :(

Reply from Microsoft Support team on 19/9/2024:
We have investigated the issue and would like to inform you that dragging and dropping the pdf file to winform of your choice is not yet supported in new Outlook for Windows.
We recommend you stay in the Classic Outlook until they are resolved, or you can switch the toggle to go between apps as often as you want. You may switch the toggle "New Outlook" off (top-right), to revert to Classic Outlook.
